# Eve: Suppress validation error details in response

Tags: python, eve

To secure my public Eve REST API, I want to avoid responses like `'{"_status": "ERR", "_error": {"code": 422, "message": "Insertion failure: 1 document(s) contain(s) error(s)"}, "_issues": {"magicfield": "requiredfield"}}'`.

Instead, I just want to return status code 401 with an empty response body (or at least an empty "_issues" field). Is there any way to do that? Authentication/authorization is not an option, because it's a public registration resource (public method POST allowed).

I already changed the status code to 401 (VALIDATION_ERROR_STATUS), but there is still the specific validation error, so an attacker could "fix" his request according to the validation error.

The aim is to only allow requests with some magic field value in it (which is validated for specific length etc) and to forbid all other requests for this resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into [event hooks](http://python-eve.org/features.html#event-hooks)? Try something like this:

```
def my_callback(resource, request, response):
    data = response.json
    del(data['_issues'])
    del(data['_error'])
    response.set_data(json.dumps(data))

app = Eve()
app.on_post_POST += my_callback
app.run
```

Comment: These event hooks are really useful for all kinds of customization. Works perfect, thanks! I also deleted _status to have a completely empty response.